# How can I wrap a function returning successive values in a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `bar(obj)` which returns successive values from an object until it's exhausted, at which point it returns `False` (ignore the fact that it's not a method on `Foo`, or that I'm returning integers – this is just an MVCE to demonstrate the consumption of *something*). I'd like to wrap that function in a generator so I can lazily iterate over the values, but I'm clearly missing some logic, because this doesn't work:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def inc(self):
        if self.counter <= 9:
            self.counter += 1
            return self.counter
        else:
            return False


def bar(obj):
    return obj.inc()


def iterbar(obj):
    res = bar(obj)
    if res:
        yield res
    else:
        raise StopIteration

foo = Foo()
lazy = iterbar(foo)
next(lazy) # this yields 1, as expected
next(lazy) # this immediately raises StopIteration from somewhere other than iterbar
```

How can I modify `iterbar` to work correctly?

Comment: `Foo` is already defined: `lazy = itertools.count()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looping to repeat the calls to `bar`. Once you call `next` a second time, it picks up where the `yield` left off, gets to the end of the function, then indicates that by raising.

Just loop, then `return` to stop:

```
def iterbar(obj):
    while True:
        res = bar(obj)
        if res:
            yield res
        else:
            return
```

Or, if you want to be fancy and have Python 3.8+, you can use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) to make this more terse:

```
def iterbar(obj):
    while res := bar(obj):
        yield res
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. Thank you! (will accept in ~6 mins)

Comment: @urschrei Np. And note, `StopIteration` is raised for you when returning from a generator function, so the explicit `raise StopIteration` is unnecessary.